# JQuery/AJAX: Functions using ID's from external content

Tags: jquery, ajax

### The Idea

I have a main PHP page that loads content in DIV's from an external file using JQuery and AJAX.

The page works as follows:

1. Main page has list of links, when link is clicked, AJAX loads an external DIV onto the page.
2. This new DIV, then has another list of links, when clicked, AJAX again loads another external DIV
3. There are now 3 DIVs containing lists of links, this process can be repeated again and again.

Each of the links in the DIV has parameters that filter results for the next DIV.

```
<div id="destination_Div01">
  <a href="?Div01=1">Link</a>
</div>
```

### The problem

```
$(document).ready(function() {                         
    $('#Destination_Div01 a').click(function(){
        $("#Destination_Div02").load("External.php"+$(this).attr('href')+" #Target_Div02");
        return false;
    });

    $('#Destination_Div02 a').click(function(){
        $("#Destination_Div03").load("External.php"+$(this).attr('href')+" #Target_Div03");
        return false;
    });
});
```

When the page is first loaded, only one DIV exists, when the new DIV is loaded, i don't think that JQuery notices that there is now a new DIV with links.

So now, when a link in the new Destination_Div02 is clicked, JQuery doesn't recognise the associated function and the browser continues to load the URL of the link. 
Instead what it is meant to do is use AJAX to pass the links URL parameters to the external PHP file, filter a recordset and return a new DIV.

How do get JQuery to function with the newly generated links?

---

### The Answer

Credit to "great_llama"
Ensure you have JQuery 1.3+ and change code to **$('#Destination_Div01 a').live("click", function(){**

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                             
    $('#Destination_Div01 a').live("click", function(){
        $("#Destination_Div02").load("External.php"+$(this).attr('href')+" #Target_Div02");
        return false;
    });

    $('#Destination_Div02 a').live("click", function(){
        $("#Destination_Div03").load("External.php"+$(this).attr('href')+" #Target_Div03");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery 1.3 came the ability to bind to future matching elements, using the [.live method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

> "Binds a handler to an event (like
>   click) for all current - and future -
>   matched element. Can also bind custom
>   events."

Comment: Lol, such a simple solution to an hour long problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use the callback parameter so after your dynamic content is loaded you can interact with its DOM.

```
$('#Destination_Div02 a').click(function(){
    $("#Destination_Div03")
    .load("External.php"+$(this).attr('href')+" #Target_Div03", null, function() {
         $(this).click( ///your click code again/// );
         //according to the docs this is the element you just loaded
    );
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put your subsequent $('div').click() inside the callback function for each previous click:

```
$('div1').click(function(){
    $('div2').load(link, data, function(){
        $('div2').click(function(){
            $('div3').load(link, data, function(){})
        })
    })
})
```

or you could give those links a class, and every time you add a new div, call a function that populates a list of links that have actions when clicked:

```
$('div1').click(function(){
    $('div2').load(link, data, function(){
        some_function();
    }
});

function some_function(){
    $('.class').click(function(){
        //logic here
    }
});
```